# Nest.js - API returns all fields of MongoDB collection instead of only fields listed in schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a simple Nest.js project with a MongoDB database. I created a schema for the *accounts* collection with only two fields: email and name. However, when I make an API request to get all accounts, I receive all the fields of the collection instead of only the fields listed in the schema.

Here is the relevant code:

```
export type AccountDocument = HydratedDocument<Account>;

@Schema()
export class Account {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

export const AccountSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Account);
---------

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Account.name) private accountModel: Model<AccountDocument>) {}

  async getAllAccounts() {
    const accounts = await this.accountModel.find().exec();
    return accounts;
  }
}

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    const accounts = await this.usersService.getAllAccounts();
    return accounts;
  }
}
```

I am concerned about the security implications of returning all the fields of the collection instead of only the fields listed in the schema. What is the best practice to avoid this issue and return only the fields listed in the schema?

I am aware that I can use the select method on the Mongoose query to specify which fields to return, but I am looking for a solution that does not require me to duplicate the schema fields elsewhere in the code.

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization this may be the best place to start, there is also an @Expose decorator you may be useable in your Dtos but it has been months since I have worked with nest